# unable to load List<> in parentView asp.net @model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem, I have a Model referenced as List  and a second Model, both combined in the ParentModel class

**Karta_Model**

```
public partial class Karta_Model
    {
        [Key]
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Login { get; set; }
    }
```

**Ustawienia_Model**

```
   public partial class Ustawienia_Model
    {
        [Key]
        public int Idp { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan NormaDzienna { get; set; }
    }
```

**ParentView**

```
public partial class ParentView
    {
        public List<Karta_Model> Model1 { get; set; }
        public Ustawienia_Model Model2 { get; set; }
    }
```

**I have previously referenced in the view like this:**

```
@model List<Karta_Model>
```

Now I try so

```
@model ParentView
```

but TextBoxFor stopped working

```
 <td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[nr_rows].DzMiesiaca, new { @class = "nrs_days", @type = "number", @readonly = true })</td>


                <td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[nr_rows].DzTygodnia, new { @class = "inputtext", @type = "text", @Value = @day, @readonly = true })</td>
```

Error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `object'

Comment: Please share your looping logic also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you changed your `Model` type to `ParentView`, you need a `foreach` loop that will loop over the `Model.Model1`:

```
@int counter=0;
foreach(var item in Model.Model1)
{
 //Now you loop over the Model properties
 <td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(item[counter].DzMiesiaca, new { @class = "nrs_days", @type = "number", @readonly = true })</td>
 <td id="td01">@Html.TextBoxFor(item[counter].DzTygodnia, new { @class = "inputtext", @type = "text", @Value = @day, @readonly = true })</td>

  //To apply indexing in a foreach loop declare a counter variable and increment it
  counter++
}
```